# How to perform custom build step for VS2012 C# Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

We have a VS2012 solution with a dozen or so C# projects in it. One of the C# projects makes use of a text file, which is converted to SQL by a separate C# tool we've written. We want to automatically invoke this TXT-2-SQL file conversion during a build whenever the TXT file has changed (Release and Debug build).

Furthermore, we'd like the Debug build to cause the SQL to be loaded into the local DB; ie, invoke one of our existing batch files, populate_db.bat, with the SQL filename as an argument (this just wraps the invocation of the mysql client and causes the SQL to be executed).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Keep your eye on the ball.  It starts out very trivial, just add a pre-build event.  But what really, really matters is *dependencies*.  You want to make sure that the custom build task runs when you change some kind of file.  A file that the MSBuild doesn't know anything about.  And that this, in turn, causes a whole bunch of *other* files to be rebuilt as well.  That's the *hard* problem to solve.  You've given no leads as to how to properly solve that problem.  Understandably, it is a very hard problem to solve.

Comment: Michael Naoumov seems to have solved the beginnings of an ideal solution...custom build tool for *.txt2db

http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/developing-custom-tool-aka-single-file-generators-for-visual-studio-2012/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my own research, I've found the following choices:

1. Custom MSBuild Task - create a separate assembly containing a class implementing ITask; reference it from our csproj; let that task do the work just described.
2. Custom Build Tool (Single File Generators) - create a separate assembly containing a class implementing [IVsSingleFileGenerator](http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/developing-custom-tool-aka-single-file-generators-for-visual-studio-2012/); register that on each dev machine; use that tool name in the 'Custom Build Tool' item in the properties of the aforementioned TXT file in our existing csproj
3. C++ Makefile project - use CustomBuild or CustomBuildTool statements in an otherwise empty [C++ Makefile project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293705.aspx); Include TXT file of interest in that other project file; Add that project to solution.
4. Target + Execs - Add custom target nodes to our existing csproj:

   <Target Name="TXT2DB" 
       AfterTargets="Build" 
   Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' " 
   Inputs="MyTextFile.txt"
   Outputs="MySqlFile.sql" 
   Label="TXT2DB" >
   <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)\Tools\txt2sql\txt2sql.exe MyTextFile.txt MySqlFile.sql" />
   <Exec Command="populate_db.bat MySqlFile.sql" />
   </Target>
5. Post Build Events - use post build events. Mentioned for completeness, but discarded b/c it happens in both debug and release, and doesn't seem to be sensitive to a TXT file change.

Currently, we've selected #4 as the easiest to impl and maintain solution, and satisfies all the requirements.